# Levantar host en rubí on rails (windows 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

buenas tardes tengo un problema cuando intento levantar el host
de mi proyecto, se llama `proyectoPrueba` y ejecuto `rails s` lo cual me da un error:

```
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/proyectoPrueba/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/proyectoPrueba/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/proyectoPrueba/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /home/vagrant/proyectoPrueba/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Ya intente instalando la gema `therubyracer` pero me sigue dando el error.

Comment: ¿pero agregaste `therubyracer` a tu `Gemfile` o sólo hiciste un `gem install therubyracer`?¿has probado instalando nodejs?

Comment: Hola, solo hice ´gem install therubyracer´ y no, no he instalado nodejs.

Comment: entonces tienes que agregarlo al gemfile y prueba nuevamente

Comment: En windows necesitas un JavaScript runtime. Prueba instalando NodeJS

Comment: Ya instale NodeJS pero me sigue marcando el mismo problema.